# How to display submitted values from Contact Form 7 form with var_dump() or printr() using plugin hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to see what is inside "$name" variable, how can i do that?

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else"); 

function wpcf7_do_something_else( &$WPCF7_ContactForm ) {
    $name = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['your-name'];
    var_dump($name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CF7 uses AJAX to submit forms and you can't see `var_dump()` in ordinary way. So through PHP you can use WordPress [debug.log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#example-wp-config-php-for-debugging) file. Iside "wp-config.php" instead of `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` write:

```php
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

Then:

```php
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else"); 

function wpcf7_do_something_else( &$WPCF7_ContactForm ) {

    $name = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['your-name'];

    ob_start();                     // start buffer capture

    var_dump($name);

    $contents = ob_get_contents();  // put the buffer into a variable
    ob_end_clean();                 // end capture
    error_log($contents);           // write the log file
}
```

As option you can do that in front-end with JS thru the [CF7 DOM events](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)

Example - when your form is submit:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;

    for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( 'your-name' == inputs[i].name ) {
            alert( inputs[i].value );
            /*
            or in console:
            console.log( inputs[i].value );
            */
            break;
        }
    }
}, false );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can i change the input values before submitting ?

Comment: @cristopher_123 I am interested in your question. After information searching i wrote [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339795/how-to-change-submitted-data-from-contact-form-7).

Comment: @cristopher_123 also i found how to var_dump CF7 through PHP. Check my edited reply.

Comment: I moved the code to an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784063/how-to-change-data-before-sending-in-contact-form-7). If it is someone else will be needed.