# Contact form 7 getting values from select with pipes

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to get country name from country drop down, where I have used pipe symbol. like this in my form

```
[text* FullName id:fullname]
[select* country id:country include_blank "United States | a@gmail.com" "Canada | a@gmail.com" "Mexico | b@gmail.com" "United Kingdom | c@gmail.com"]
```

I have used different-2 email with country name because i need to sand email to company employee according to country name. In email template i have used `[country]` to get email and `[_raw_country]` to get country name that is working fine.
I am trying to get country name in function.php file to save it in database by this way.

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail( $form_to_DB ) {
    //set your db details
    $mydb = new wpdb('user','password','databasename','localhost');    
    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ) 
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();        
    $fullname = $formData['FullName'];    
    $country = $formData['country'];

    $mydb->insert( 'mytable', array( 'fullname' =>$fullname,'country' =>$country), array( '%s' ) );
}
```

But it gives nothing. if i try to get like this

```
$country = $formData['country'][0];
```

it gives me only email id like a@gmail.com I have tryed `$country = $formData['country'][1];`
It give me nothing. I have also tryed `$country = $formData['_raw_country'];` But not get luck.

This is the reference document
https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Comment: You can try using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361457/trying-to-get-contact-form-7-post-data-to-debug-to-screen/60361505#60361505 to send your formdata to the error log and see what the results are.

Comment: ["FullName"]=>
  string(6) "Deepak"
  ["country"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(21) "a@gmail.com"
  }

Comment: I have follows what you suggest ob_start();
    var_dump($formData);
    error_log(ob_get_clean());and  got output shows in above comment.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate (of sorts) of your other question?

Answer (score 2):

you need something like this:

```
<?php
// Get the submitted data
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( ! $submission
     or ! $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data() ) {
    return;
}

// Get the contact form additional data
$contact_form = $submission->get_contact_form();

// get the tag used in the form
$mail_tags=$contact_form->scan_form_tags();

// search into tags for country
$key = array_search('country', array_column($mail_tags, 'name'));

// get the country pipes values
$pipes = new WPCF7_Pipes( $mail_tags[$key]->raw_values );

// get an array with the pipes
$pipes_array = $pipes->to_array();

// get the choosen value
$pipes_val = array_search( $posted_data['country'][0], array_column($pipes_array, 1));

// finally!
error_log(print_r($posted_data['country'],true));
error_log(print_r("in",true));
error_log(print_r($pipes_array[$pipes_val][0],true));
```

Comment: I have tried error_log(print_r($mail_tags[$key],true)); it is for country tag. and output come like this

Comment: I have posted my output here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-country-name-when-used-pipe/#post-14492875, It only give me all details of country dropdown except selected country details.

Comment: ciao deepak, i've updated the answer to get the array of pipe values

Comment: It gives me all values in place of selected.

Comment: it was missing the [0] at the end of $posted_data['country']! fixed

Comment: It will work if email id is different for different country. But in my case email id like same for 10 country and for another 15 it is different.

Comment: I suppose it's hard to fix because the only data we get with WPCF7_Submission::get_instance is the chosen email (without any key) so if the emails were the same we can't find into array for the exact corrispondence.

Comment: Ones you have the `WPCF7_Pipes` class you can call `$pipes->do_pipe($formData['country'])`

Answer (score 0):

I posted this answer in your other question. This should work.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'cf7_pipes_so_67686211');
function cf7_pipes_so_67686211( $contact_form ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $mydb = new wpdb('user','password','database','localhost');
    
    // Get Form Tags
    $tags = $contact_form->scan_form_tags();
    $pipe_array = array();
    // Find the Values of the Pipes
    foreach ($tags as $tag){
        if ($tag->name === 'primarybusiness'){
           $pipe_array = $tag->pipes->to_array();
        }
    }
    // Get the form data
    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ) {
        $formData = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
        $fullname = $formData['FullName'];
        foreach ($pipe_array as $value) {
            // Compare and find the pipe value
            if ( $posted_data['primarybusiness'][0] === $value[1] ){
                $primarybusiness = $value[0];
            }
        }
        $mydb->insert( 'mytable', array( 'fullname'=>$fullname,'primarybusiness'=>$primarybusiness), array( '%s' ) );
    }
}
```