# Contact form 7 data sending to API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

I want to send my contact for 7 data to an API on submission. For this purpose i have used following code.

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent','crazy_cf7_api_sender');

function crazy_cf7_api_sender( $contact_form ){
    $title = $contact_form -> title;

    echo "Test";
    if( $title == 'Committee Club'){
    
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        
        if( $submission ){
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
                $committee_club = $posted_data['committee-club'];
                $language = $posted_data['language'];
                $Intrest = $posted_data['Intrest'];

         
                $url = 'https://staging.walee.pk/api/tracking/newWordPressHook';

        $args = array(
'method' => 'POST',
'orderId' => 220,
);

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );

// error check
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
}
else {
   echo 'Response: <pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
        }
    }
}
```

I get reference from

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOjpqHFM9v8

https://wp-kama.com/function/wp_remote_post

But when I submit my form i am getting following error message:

**{code: "invalid_json", message: "the response is not a valid json response."}**

Please anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Here is how you can debug output from contact form - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361457/trying-to-get-contact-form-7-post-data-to-debug-to-screen/60361505#60361505 -- to me it seems like your problem is your API call is lacking the correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should not `echo` anything in your code because the hook wpcf7_mail_sent is called in Ajax and it expects a `JSON` output.

Plase remove any `echo`, `var_dump`, `print_r` or anything else that prints anything from your code

```
 echo 'Response: <pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrea for replaying. I removed echo but still i am getting same error.

Comment: You also have `echo "Test";` at the top. You need to remove all echo/var_dump/print_r

Comment: You can also use the Chrome Console or Firefox Console to check the network calls made to ajax to understand exactly what you're printing

Comment: I have removed all echo and var dump from file. Now error removed. Please can you let me know how i can check data is posting in api or not?