# WP Contact Form 7 - Page with data before sending

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to show all data from form fields on the page and two buttons - change and send if ok.
And then send mail on ok button click.

I know about this code:

```
    add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body' );

  function wpcf7_add_text_to_mail_body($contact_form){

   $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        print_r($posted_data)
    }
}
```

But I can't understand how to make the button that sends an email on.

P.S. I'm using Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms plugin and need to show data and buttons after the last step

Comment: Until now you described what you want to do - but What is the question exactly where is your problem ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen you're right, sorry. edited the post

Comment: You can't `print_r` output from before send mail, since it's a function with no screen output (unless you've disabled cf7 javascript.) With that said, I still can't understand what you're trying to do with the posted data?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361457/trying-to-get-contact-form-7-post-data-to-debug-to-screen

Comment: @HowardE I'm trying to create a page (or modal window) with all form fields and user's data to show user is it correct. If it's not user presses the Return button and fills form again, and if all is ok user presses Send button and all data goes to email

Comment: `wpcf7_before_send_mail` happens after submit though.  I don't see how you'd get to where you want to go with that. You need to get the cake l values of the form using jQuery and make a load modal button while keeping the form submit button disabled until another action occurs.

Comment: Although you could use the &$abort to prevent the mail from sending, but what you have now isn't really anything that would help you.

Comment: If you come up with something more solid, I will definitely help you.

Comment: Instead of `print_r()` you could just use [mai()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) ..