# PHP wordpress wp_safe_remote_post write server response to text file

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, fwrite

In Wordpress (PHP) i'm using Contact Form 7 (CF7) as the UI and sending the data via an API with the function on_submit below. Would like to have the success or fail response data logged to make sure everything is working so thought i'd write that to a simple text file using the function custom_logs. It does write to the text file but then the process never continues on to the CF7 plugin to indicate the POST was a success or fail, it just hangs after hitting submit on the UI side. I believe something about writing to the file is interrupting the flow and then is just stops from CF7's POV. I rarely write anything in PHP so not 100% sure what the issue is? Anyone have an idea how to solve it, I can't find anything. Thanks

```
function on_submit( $form, &$abort, $submission )
{
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    $firstname = sanitize_text_field($data['first-name']);

    $response = wp_safe_remote_post("https://www.api.com", [
        'body' => json_encode([
            'firstname' => $firstname,
        ]),
    ]);

    if ( is_wp_error($response) ) {
        $abort = TRUE;

        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        $result = json_decode($body);

        $submission->set_response($result->error);
        $submission->set_status('api_failed');
    } else {
        $abort = FALSE;

        $body_success = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
        $result_success = json_decode($body_success);
        
        custom_logs("WP API: " . $result_success);
    }
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'on_submit', 10, 3);


function custom_logs($message) { 
    if(is_array($message)) { 
        $message = json_encode($message); 
    } 
    $file = fopen("custom_logs.log","a"); 
    echo fwrite($file, "\n" . date('Y-m-d h:i:s') . " :: " . $message); 
    fclose($file); 
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$response` ?

Comment: Nothing interesting. Just a response by the API's server. Something like: 

{"headers":{},"body":"Data received","response":{"code":200,"message":"OK"},"cookies":[],"filename":null,"http_response":{"data":null,"headers":null,"status":null}}

Comment: Is custom_logs throwing any errors?  It seems like you're passing a string and an object since you've used json_decode $result_success... right?

Comment: If this helps you at all - This is how I usually debug CF7 `before_send_mail` functions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361457/trying-to-get-contact-form-7-post-data-to-debug-to-screen/60361505

Comment: Found it! It's the echo in custom_logs. Just removed that and the function no longer halts the process.