# Load Ultimate Member dynamic email in Contact Form 7 send email

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, ultimate-member

I am using the Ultimate Member plugin and I need CF7 to load the email of each user for sending that are within the public profiles that are the members.
Here I leave the code that I have used but it only works for me if I put an email in string format, `$dynamic_email = 'mail@mail.com';` instead of `$dynamic_email = $value;`
How do I make the following dynamic code work for me?

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
        $form_id = $contact_form->id();
        if($form_id == 799 ){
            $valor = get_the_author_meta('user_email', um_profile_id()); // um_profile_id() - Profile ID in the Ultimate Member plugin
            $dynamic_email = $valor;
            $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
            $properties['mail']['recipient'] = $dynamic_email;
            $contact_form->set_properties($properties);
            return $contact_form;
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

I need to load the value of `get_the_author_meta('user_email', um_profile_id())` so that I upload the mail in each of the public profiles.

Thank you very much for the help.

Summarizing this function if it works, it manages to change the sending email and sends the form:

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
        $form_id = $contact_form->id();
        if($form_id == 799 ){
            $dynamic_email = 'mail@mail.com';
            $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
            $properties['mail']['recipient'] = $dynamic_email;
            $contact_form->set_properties($properties);
            return $contact_form;
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

This other one that is the one I need does not work and does not send the mail showing the error "An error occurred while trying to send your message. Please try again later." and I do not understand or know the reason why it does not work if I only make a small change and it also returns an email:

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
        $form_id = $contact_form->id();
        if($form_id == 799 ){
            $valor = get_the_author_meta('user_email', um_profile_id()); // um_profile_id() - Profile ID in the Ultimate Member plugin
            $dynamic_email = $valor;
            $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
            $properties['mail']['recipient'] = $dynamic_email;
            $contact_form->set_properties($properties);
            return $contact_form;
        }
    }
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `um_profile_id` the same as current user id?

Comment: No, it is the profile ID within the members file, if you access each of the profiles you see all the data and there is the email of that user and they are public profiles anyone can access.
The email is displayed even if you are not logged in.

Comment: If you look here [debug cf7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361457/trying-to-get-contact-form-7-post-data-to-debug-to-screen/60361505#60361505) can you use this to debug what `$valor` is.  Can you check to make sure it's what you want?

Comment: The idea is to access that email whether you are logged in or not and this Ultimate Member feature does that.
The purpose of all this is to load a contact form for each user logged in ultimate member and that anyone can send an email to that user's profile email.

Comment: Back to my previous comment, and debug using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361457/trying-to-get-contact-form-7-post-data-to-debug-to-screen/60361505#60361505 method, you'd see that 
 `um_profile_id` will return `0` when used with the `before_send_mail` hook.  You need to create a hidden form field passing the user_id or user_email through the form so that you can retrieve it.   So you'll need to make a custom form tag first.

Comment: https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/124-umprofileid states that this will return the _"requested member ID on the profile page, current user ID on other pages and 0 if the user is not logged in."_ But I am guessing, inside the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` callback, the actual "current page" context is not that of your user profile page (at least not if you are using AJAX to submit the CF7 form.)

Comment: It would probably make more sense if you executed `um_profile_id` within the context of the actual user profile page, output that ID value somewhere into that page - and then have JavaScript transfer it into a hidden field inside your CF7 form. And then inside your `wpcf7_before_send_mail` callback, you grab the ID from the form parameters instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the `um_profile_id()` to the form data, you need to add it to the form (as stated in the comments by myself and @cbroe).  To do that, either you need to pass it using javascript to a hidden form field, or simply create a custom form tag.  Below uses a custom form tag.

Add `[um_profile_id]` to your form, and the below function will work.

Additionally, since wpcf7_before_send_mail is an action hook you don't have to return anything, the $contact_form object is passed by reference and updated when you set the property.

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    if ( $submission && 799 === $contact_form->id() ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        if ( isset( $posted_data['um-profile-id'] ) ) {
            $user                            = get_user_by( 'id', absint( $posted_data['um-profile-id'] ) );
            $properties                      = $contact_form->get_properties();
            $properties['mail']['recipient'] = $user->user_email;
            $contact_form->set_properties( $properties );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );


add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'um_profile_id_form_tag' );
function um_profile_id_form_tag() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'um_profile_id', 'cf7_get_um_profile_id' );
}

function cf7_get_um_profile_id() {
    $output = sprintf( '<input type="hidden" name="um-profile-id" value="%s"/>', um_profile_id() );
    return $output;
}
```

This method has been tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot, it works perfectly.
I will often go through the web to try to help as much as I can and my knowledge allows me, a big greeting and thanks again for all your work and help.

Comment: @neoset please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer so it may help others.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm new and I didn't know how to accept the answer, thanks for the help in the indication.
Regards and thanks for everything.