# "wpcf7_validate_text" filter stopped working after Contact Form 7 plugin update to 5.6

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I was using wpcf7_validate_text for all input type text as a custom validation in function.php, however after updating the form i could not see the my custom validation on input type text and textarea.

Can you please help how can i update those again.  Code is given below

```js
/* Code in Function.php */
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'custom_firstname_confirmation_validation_filter', 5, 2  );
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 
            'custom_firstname_confirmation_validation_filter', 5, 2  );
            
function custom_firstname_confirmation_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( 'firstname' == $tag->name ) { 
        $firstname = isset( $_POST['firstname'] ) ? trim( $_POST['firstname'] ) : '';

    if(empty($firstname)) {
        $msg = 'first name is Required';
        $result->invalidate( $tag, $msg);
    }
    else if (strlen((string)$firstname) < 6 || strlen((string)$firstname) > 12) {
          $msg = 'first name is not valid';
          $result->invalidate( $tag, $msg);
      }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

```html
<p>*All fields are required</p>
[response]

[select* inquiry "Business Enquiry" "Media Enquiry" ]
[phonetext phone ]
[text* phonenum class:phonenum placeholder "Phone number" ]
[select* title "Mr" "Ms" "Mrs"]
[email* email placeholder "Email" ]
[text* firstname placeholder "First Name" ]
[text* lastname placeholder "Last Name" ]
[textarea textarea-854 placeholder "Enter your message here"]
[checkbox checkbox-57 checked id:chk1 "" ]
[acceptance acceptance624 id:iagree ]
[submit class:btn-theme class:btn-submit "Enquire"]
```

Comment: How are these being added on the frontend? autocomplete:off

Comment: Removed those. As it does not work.

Comment: I tested your form with my function, and it works as expected.  Perhaps you have some other plugin or jquery error causing problems?  https://snipboard.io/cGUQz9.jpg  - Your function is still wrong, as it puts the return in the wrong place, so if your condition isn't met, there won't be any `$result`

Comment: Can you please share your function if that is alright with you where return will be in proper place. Thank you Howard.

Comment: It's my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If your code above is exactly how you have it, then you have the return in the wrong page, and unless your tag matches, you'll get an error.

```
function custom_firstname_confirmation_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( 'firstname' === $tag->name ) {
        $first_name = isset( $_POST['firstname'] ) ? trim( $_POST['firstname'] ) : '';
        if ( empty( $first_name ) ) {
            $msg = 'First name is required';
            $result->invalidate( $tag, $msg );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Actually it was working before the update.  I am getting this JavaScript error which was not there before:

index.js?ver=5.6:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': ':where( input, textarea, select ):enabled' is not a valid selector.
    at Object.q [as validate] (/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/index.js?ver=5.6:1:11166)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/index.js?ver=5.6:1:21085)

Comment: Regardless of if it worked before... there is/was a mistake in your code that threw an error for me.  For the JS error post your form tags in the question.

Comment: Yeah there was a curly missing my bad. Added my form tags in question.  I am trying to filter for example as when firstname is empty i will show my custom error msg instead of the generic one that says "The is field is required"

Comment: Please check my updated code it is working when you fill something in the field, on empty it shows generic error rather the ones that i defined.

Comment: Yet again, your code works. (at least now that you've updated it) If something is preventing it, verify that your theme or some other plugin isn't conflicting with your code. You can try changing the priority from 5 to 99 and/or follow this concept https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361457/trying-to-get-contact-form-7-post-data-to-debug-to-screen to debug your filter code and verify it's firing.

Comment: I got my answer here: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342300/contact-form-7-custom-validation-doesnt-get-called

In my case, it was not working because is_required() executes first than my function. So removing * from my contact form backend like [email* email placeholder "Email" ]
and changing priority in the function did the job for me.